# Graphics.Drawstring's drawn Font Size changed in other PC

Tags: c#

I am creating an C# Winforms for printing QR code with some text drawn over an empty image (`logo1.bmp`) with

```
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(logo1);
        StringFormat stringformat_Model = new StringFormat();
        stringformat_Model.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far;
        stringformat_Model.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Far;
        g.DrawString(Stringformat_Model, new Font("Bahnschrift Condensed", 16, FontStyle.Regular), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), new Point(467, 265), SomeString);
```

I got the text in desired alignment and font size in my Laptop. but when I install the Application in other PC the text size has reduced. font was not changed but font size changed.

[Image from other PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ument.png)

[Image from my PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSQ5K.png)

Comment: Are all the settings the same on both machines? Resolution, magnification,  etc

Comment: Sounds like a DPI issue.

Comment: The default unit is points, so this is supposed to happen.  Use [GraphicsUnit.Pixel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.font.-ctor?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#system-drawing-font-ctor(system-string-system-single-system-drawing-graphicsunit)) instead.